# redirect to POST with javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have 2 controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model, string someString)
{
//..
return View()
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
```

I'm trying to find a way what would allow me to navigate directly to Post method from a controller (some other controller). I've heard the is a way to do it in javascript, but I can't find it anywhere. The idea would be to set a filed in model, and check it at beginning of a view - if it's set, do the javascript thing to redirect immediatly to Post action in controller. If anyone knows how to do it, I would aprreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to check, on page load, if the form has been filled out and if so immediately post it to the appropriate action?

If so

```
$(function() {
    if () { // determine here if the form has been filled out and completed
        $('#theform').submit(); // this posts the form, which will hit the post action
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is i dont know much about javascript so I did not manage to get your code working, but I used some jquery and it seems to work now
          $.post('Controller/Action', function (data) {
          });